# Get Difference of two dates retrieve from MS Access database using visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

```vb
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ITemID, ItemName, ItemDescription, ItemQuantity, ItemBorrowedDate, ItemReturnDate FROM BorrowedItem order by ID DESC", conn)
Dim dt As New DataTable
da.Fill(dt)

OverDueList.DataSource = dt.DefaultView

Dim ItemReturenedDate As New Date
Dim DateToday As Integer
Dim DateDiff As New Date

ItemReturenedDate = dt.Rows(0)("ItemReturnDate")

DateDiff = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, ItemReturenedDate, DateTimePicker1.Value)`
```

I tried that code to generate output but my knowledge was not that good. i need help, it could be a great help if someone would notice it

Comment: Are you trying to use VB.NET/Visual Studio or VBA/MS-Access?

Comment: Im using MS access as my database and visual basic in my code sir

Comment: Then change the tag. Are you using vb.net or VB6 or VBA? Use appropriate tag. What's wrong with code - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Edit question. Don't use a variable name same as function name.

Comment: Im using visual studio and i think my code was wrong, i didn't debug it because i know it was wrong. just want to find another way to calculate the difference of 2 dates from my database

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, then you are not using VBA. Make sure the tutorials you are using are for the right language. Calling it "Visual Basic" is not specific enough.

Comment: my fault, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you looking to send all rows to say a grid?

then this:

```
Dim strSQL As String =
  "Select ITemID, ItemName, ItemDescription, ItemQuantity, ItemBorrowedDate, ItemReturnDate,
  (ItemReturnDate - ItemBorroedDate) as MyDays
  FROM BorrowedItem order by ID DESC"

dim dt as DataTable = MyRst(strSQL)
```

So, you can return MyDays for each row, and then say send the data table to a data grid view.

And I get VERY tired very fast typing over confection string and command objects, so you can use this routine (over and over).

```
Function MyRst(strSQL As String) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)
        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```vb
Dim ItemReturenedDate As Date
Dim Days As Long

ItemReturenedDate = dt.Rows(0)("ItemReturnDate")
Days = DateTimePicker1.Value.Subtract(ItemReturenedDate).TotalDays
```

Comment: OMG it works. 100% works. Thanks a lot for the help. saves me from stressing hhahaha thank you godbless sir